# ¿Cómo se puede usar la librería Shap sobre objetos serializados con Pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

Tengo un modelo guardado con la librería Pickle sobre el que me gustaría trabajar con la librería Shap.

```
Modelo_Lasso = gridsearch.best_estimator_
Modelo_Lasso

import pickle

with open("Modelo_Lasso.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(Modelo_Lasso, f)

with open("Modelo_Lasso.pkl", "rb") as f:
    ModeloLasso = pickle.load(f)
```

Cuando instancio la clase, y le paso los parámetros, me salta un TypeError señalando que `"'Pipeline' object is not callable"`.

```
import shap

# Calculamos los valores SHAP para obtener la importancia global de cada variable en el modelo
shap_values = shap.KernelExplainer(model=ModeloLasso, data=X_train).shap_values(X_train)
# Mostramos el resultado en un gráfico de barras (plot_type="bar")
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar")
Provided model function fails when applied to the provided data set.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 4
      1 import shap
      3 # Calculamos los valores SHAP para obtener la importancia global de cada variable en el modelo
----> 4 shap_values = shap.KernelExplainer(model=ModeloLasso, data=X_train).shap_values(X_train)
      5 # Mostramos el resultado en un gráfico de barras (plot_type="bar")
      6 shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_train, plot_type="bar")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\explainers\_kernel.py:96, in Kernel.__init__(self, model, data, feature_names, link, **kwargs)
     94 self.keep_index_ordered = kwargs.get("keep_index_ordered", False)
     95 self.data = convert_to_data(data, keep_index=self.keep_index)
---> 96 model_null = match_model_to_data(self.model, self.data)
     98 # enforce our current input type limitations
     99 assert isinstance(self.data, DenseData) or isinstance(self.data, SparseData), \
    100        "Shap explainer only supports the DenseData and SparseData input currently."

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\_legacy.py:123, in match_model_to_data(model, data)
    121         out_val = model.f(data.convert_to_df())
    122     else:
--> 123         out_val = model.f(data.data)
    124 except Exception:
    125     print("Provided model function fails when applied to the provided data set.")

TypeError: 'Pipeline' object is not callable
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Se puede usar un modelo cargado con Pickle con las clases de la librería Shap?
Y en caso afirmativo: ¿Cómo hacerlo?

Comment: No se sobre modelos ni shap, pero por lo que vi, si tu modelo es derivado en algún punto de shap.models.Model (probablemente, eso signifcaría que `isinstance(Modelo_Lasso, shap.models.Model)` devuelve True), entonces, podrías usar los métodos save y load, que parecen guardar y cargar respectivamente el modelo a partir de archivos. Y en el fondo, usa pickle de una forma especial para guardar y cargar correctamente.

Comment: Acá tenés las fuentes de [la clase base Model](https://github.com/shap/shap/blob/master/shap/models/_model.py) y el modulo [_serializable](https://github.com/shap/shap/blob/master/shap/_serializable.py) que parece ser usado por Model.